# Regular Expression Wordpress redirection plugin

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, redirect

I'm using the Redirection plugin to Wordpress, but can't get this regex to work. I'm not an expert on regex at all, so I guess I'm doing something wrong.

```
/(.*)/(.*)/?rel=old
/$1/$2/?rel=new
```

When doing this I end up with:
http://domain.se/something/somestuff/?/?rel=new

It should be:
http://domain.se/something/somestuff/?rel=new

Why is it not working and what is that extra /?/

Comment: What's the string you're trying to match?

Comment: It's `?rel=old` changing into `?rel=new`. The rest of the url should remain the same as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to escape the `?`.

```
/(.*)/(.*)/\?rel=old
/$1/$2/?rel=new
```

In regex, `?` means *match the preceding character/group zero or one times* - so your original regex was looking for an optional `/` character immediately before `rel=old`.  Of course it didn't find this, and so instead the text matched by the second capture group expanded to encompass the `/?` characters before `rel=old`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer, solved the problem and saved the day!

Comment: Thanks.  Be sure to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you're satisfied (looks like you haven't done that on any of your previous questions).  Accepting an answer earns you reputation points, you know...

Comment: I tried to accept it when I wrote my comment, but it was to fast it said. It's done now!